# CSS Transition Choppy for Width + Height + Transform

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to expand an image with animation from grid view to a "lightbox" view.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="cats.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="cats.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="cats.jpg"></li>
    .
    .
    .
</ul>
```

JS

```
function clickHandler(event) {
    var elem = event.target;
    elem.classList.add('animate');
    elem.style.transform = 'translate3d(x, y, z)';  // x, y, z are calculated px
    elem.style.width = w + 'px'; // w and h are also calculated
    elem.style.height = h + 'px';
}
```

Everything works, but the animation is choppy. When I remove the width and height, it's a lot smoother. So i tried using transform (ie. scale(3, 3)) instead, it also has a smooth animation, but the image is blurry.

I'm not sure if this is a browser limitation or if I'm taking the wrong approach.

Comment: Have you tried hiding backface visibility? The images are huge by any chance?

Comment: Think this the other way around, scale down a bigger image as if it was your thumbnail, say `scale(0.3)` then perform the animation back to `scale(1)`.

Comment: scaling an image to 3x will make it blurry. You can try making the default to be `scale(0.33)` and make it `scale(1)` to get it to maximum zoom.

Comment: @sabithpocker i have `backface-visibility: hidden;` set on the animated element, and the images are around 100k and 620x1130

Comment: Resizing images in browser using width/height is usually expensive. And can be choppy if done for many images or large images.

Comment: @Ricky & sabithpocker i'll give the scale down to scale(1) a try

Comment: If you are using animations extensively I would recommend using some library like greensock to take care of the performance. But for just one animation it would be an overkill

Comment: @sabithpocker only one image animating at a time, yeah. if i can't get the css to work, i might use gsap